# Save a rgl 3D scatterplot in a lossless format like svg or pdf

Tags: r, rgl, scatter3d

What I want to achieve is, to show a 3D graph in rgl, rotate it into the view I would like to show and then save it to a file. I know that I can do this with the `rgl.snapshot` function like this:

```
library(rgl)

x <- runif(20)
y <- runif(20)
z <- runif(20)
plot3d(x, y, z)
rgl.snapshot("rgl.snapshot.png")
```

The problem is, that `rgl.snapshot` produces a file in the screen resolution, hence not high resolution enough for print. I have no way to influence the resolution the file get`s saved in. In general even better would be if I would be able to save the file in a vector format like pdf or svg.

My Idea was to save the rotation of the current view and use it with another function that produces a non-interactive 3d scatterplot like `scatter3D` from the `plot3D` package. To save the rotation matrix I did the following:

```
rotationMatrix <- rgl.projection()
```

You can also do it like this:

```
rotationMatrix <- par3d()$modelMatrix
```

The rotation matrix looks like this:

```
$model
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.9584099  0.0000000 0.0000000 -0.4726846
[2,] 0.0000000  0.3436644 0.9792327 -0.6819317
[3,] 0.0000000 -0.9442102 0.3564116 -3.6946754
[4,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000  1.0000000

$proj
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 3.732051 0.000000  0.000000   0.00000
[2,] 0.000000 3.732051  0.000000   0.00000
[3,] 0.000000 0.000000 -3.863703 -14.36357
[4,] 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000   0.00000

$view
     x      y  width height 
     0      0    256    256
```

Now my question is how I get from this rotation matrix to the arguments `phi` and `theta` which are used by the `scatter3D` function.

```
library(plot3D)

# phi = ?
# theta = ?
pdf("scatter3D.pdf")
scatter3D(x, y, z, pch=20, phi = 20, theta =30, col="black")
dev.off()
```

I know there is math to extract a rotation angle from a rotation matrix. I don't really get how to apply it in my case. Especially since the matrix has 4 rows and columns. I would expect 3 of each... Next problem is that `scatter3D` uses only two rotation axes (theta gives the azimuthal direction and phi the colatitude), so I would have to convert from a 3-axis rotation to the same rotation resulting from a two-axis rotation. I think the rotation axis of phi is defined by the rotation of theta.

If there is another way to save a rgl snapshot in a lossless format I would be happy to learn about it!

Comment: You can change the resolution of a snapshot by changing the size of the original rgl window.   You're limited to screen size, so this might not be enough.  You can sometimes use rgl.postscript for a vector format, but it doesn't handle all scenes properly.

Comment: Arrg, yeah, this is it. It works for me. I just didn't realize this function is already there in the package.

Comment: snapshot3d("3d.pdf" fmt = "pdf")
Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330293/2187956

Comment: Warning: 'snapshot3d("3dplot.pdf", fmt = "pdf")':
  webshot = TRUE requires the webshot2 package and Chrome browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest (R-forge only; see [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl) for how to get it) version of rgl has a function rglToBase() that returns the phi and theta values you'd need.  There's also rgl.postscript() as mentioned in my Apr 24 comment that saves in a lossless format (but can't save everything).

Edited to add:  A very new addition is the `writeASY()` function.  This writes out Asymptote source code to draw the image in various formats, mainly intended for LaTeX documents.  See http://asymptote.sourceforge.net.  This is still a little limited (subscenes aren't supported, surface lighting isn't perfect, etc.) but it's getting there.  Suggestions would be welcome.