# Is there a way to save an rgl 3D plot with high resolution?

Tags: r, rgl, plot3d

I have a 3D plot from plot3d() function in rgl package, but the function rgl.postscript() is not working (the error message says it stopped working for my version of rgl - newest).

Is there any other way to save a frame of the 3D plot, and with high resolution (publication intent)?

Comment: I have used `rgl.snapshot` with the graphics window set to be as large as would fit on my screen to generate a PNG file that was good enough for publication. (I think I tried farting around with a virtual X11 frame buffer but don't think that got anywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Chrome browser installed, then install the `webshot2` package and then `rgl::snapshot3d()` will take high quality images.  For example, if you want 300 dpi resolution in a 3in x 3in plot, use

```
snapshot3d(width = 900, height = 900)
```

You may need to adjust line widths, etc., that doesn't happen automatically with `snapshot3d()`.